# private/public cryptography with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have to do something like this with Node.js (crypto module).

http://www.devco.net/archives/2006/02/13/public_-_private_key_encryption_using_openssl.php

Is this possible with the methods in crypto module?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the following libraries

- [node-rsa](https://github.com/chrisa/node-rsa)
- [ursa](https://github.com/Obvious/ursa)

Hopefully they help.